# Visual Studio randomly pops up an error screen

Tags: visual-studio, error-handling, popup

Visual Studio is throwing these exceptions, which don't really have any affect.

[image: Exceptions]

I catch these exceptions and write them to a log file. But for some reason Visual Studio randomly decided to break on some of these and throw a pop-up screen, which then makes my app stop running and that's something I need to avoid.

It's even running in release mode and I turned off all the "Break When Thrown" checkboxes.

[image: "break when thrown" checkboxes]

Does anyone have any idea why I am still getting these breaks?